# How to retrieve value from object?

Tags: jquery, json

How can I grab only the value that is after `image` in this object? I want only: `/images/aluguer/7d9a3d3c-08bd-44a8-a081-b6a764cc7ef4.jpg`

```js
{
  "data": {
    "file": {
      "tmp_name": "/private/var/tmp/phpQhqg0D",
      "error": 0,
      "name": "ferrari3.jpg",
      "type": "image/jpeg",
      "size": 336044
    },
    "image": "/images/aluguer/7d9a3d3c-08bd-44a8-a081-b6a764cc7ef4.jpg"
  }
}
```

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: I used JSON.stringify(response) to put it inside a input type text value, but i only need whats is inside "image" key. I made research but nothing worked.

Comment: Note that what you have is an object, not JSON. As such you can just access it by key name; `response.data.image`

Comment: I tryed $.grep, without luck

Comment: response.data.image is the correct answer.
Thank you @Rory McCrossan